# Discord.py NameError: name 'create_guild' is not defined

Tags: discord, discord.py

Trying to create a guild using dicord.py and getting unexpected error

```
import asyncio
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    await create_guild("Bot World")
client.run("Token")
```

I am trying to create a guild using a bot so that it has ownership by using the create_guild command but I'm getting the error

```
File "/home/osass/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osass/Documents/Python/Ppl in irl bot.py", line 7, in on_ready
    await create_guild("Bot World")
NameError: name 'create_guild' is not defined
```

I don't know the problem and fairly new to coding so if you could explain the problem as well it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that method is on the `client` object, so `client.create_guild(name="Bot World")` should work.

Comment: Now I get the error:                                                                             

File "/home/osass/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osass/Documents/Python/Ppl in irl bot.py", line 7, in on_ready
    await client.create_guild("Bot World")
TypeError: Client.create_guild() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Ah, looks like `name` is a keyword only argument now as of 2.0 (meaning you need to specify the parameter in the function call).

`client.create_guild(name="Bot World")`

Here's more info: https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/